# Where can I see netrw plugin revision history or changelog?

Tags: netrw

Is there a place where the `netrw` source code repository is hosted, so I can view its revision history? If not, is there at least a changelog somewhere?

If I do `git log` on `netrw.vim` in the `vim` repository, all I see is "Update runtime files" commits, which changes bunch of plugins at the same time and is not informative at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite a repository but [netrw script](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1075) seems to fit the bill (at least until 2014, or netrw v. 150).

From then on you can find the complete history in the file `vim/runtime/doc/pi_netrw.txt`, the reference manual for `netrw`, in chapter **12 - History**. You can find that information at [`:help netrw-history`](https://vimhelp.org/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw-history).

Under [`:help netrw-debug`](https://vimhelp.org/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw-debug), the author lists [an URL](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW) where to find the latest development version of the plug-in, but it seems only a Vimball (zip file) is available from there, no links to a public source control repository, so it seems one is not really made available by the original author.

<sup>(thanks for giving me the impetus to find that :-))</sup>

Comment: Thanks. I still wonder if there is a repo somewhere, but at least I found some answers to my questions in that file.

Comment: @guntbert I added a few more details, including a link to `:help netrw-history` where that information can be looked up easily. I hope you agree with the edits. Feel free to modify if you'd like.

Comment: @filbranden no worries - I am always stymied by the sheer amount of `:help` topics.